# StreamBuilder flutter handle ConnectionState.waiting

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

How can I see the last data of stream builder after Navigation instead of `CircularProgressIndicator` for waiting state?

I think It will be with `initialData` but how can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have `initialData` to `StreamBuilder`, for this either pass Harcoded value or any value from the network which you are getting before using `StreamBuilder`

**For Ex:**

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: signUpBloc.outFirstName,
    initialData: YourData, 
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      _controller.value = TextEditingValue(text: "${snapshot.data}"); // assign value to controller this way
      return TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        onChanged: signUpBloc.inFirstName,
      );
    },
  );
```